# How to embed Google font in iText Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, itext

I am using [iText](https://itextpdf.com/en) to generate PDF in Java Android App. How do I embed [Roboto font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) to below snippet.

```
private void createPdf() throws FileNotFoundException {
    String pdfPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
    File file = new File(pdfPath, "iText7.pdf");

    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(file);
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

    List list = new List();
    list.add("React Native");
    list.add("Java");
    list.add("Kotlin");
    list.add("Swift");

    document.add(list);
    document.close();

    Toast.makeText(this, "PDF Created Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One of the easy ways is to download the font file from the website (`Download family` button on the top right), get the right font file from the archive (the standard choice is `Roboto-Regular.ttf`), embed this file into your application, then get the file input stream with something like `getResources().openRawResource(...)` and then you can use your font in iText if you pass it to `PdfFontFactory.createFont`!

The code would look similar to the following snippet:

```
Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StreamUtil.inputStreamToArray(getResources().openRawResource("path/to/Roboto-Regular.ttf")), PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);

List list = new List();
list.setFont(font);
list.add("React Native");
list.add("Java");
list.add("Kotlin");
list.add("Swift");

document.add(list);

document.close();
```